# How to run a regression for a given value of a parameter and represent this in a plot and stagazer?

Tags: r

Given the linear model:

```r
    data(wage1)
    reg_wage1 <- lm(lwage ~ female + educ + (female * educ), data = wage1)

stargazer(reg_wage1, type = "text")
===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                               lwage           
-----------------------------------------------
female                        -0.360*          
                              (0.185)          
                                               
educ                         0.077***          
                              (0.009)          
                                               
female:educ                   -0.0001          
                              (0.015)          
                                               
Constant                     0.826***          
                              (0.118)          
                                               
-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    526            
R2                             0.300           
Adjusted R2                    0.296           
Residual Std. Error      0.446 (df = 522)      
F Statistic           74.649*** (df = 3; 522)  
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Create a line graph that compares each gender's wage growth (female is a data type that can only be 1 or 0. 1 means yes this is a female and 0 means no.), illustrates two graphs corresponding to different values of $delta_0$ and $delta_1$.

#### My attempt:

```r
    plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,16), ylim=c(-1,1), ylab="Log Wage", xlab="Education", main = "Men vs Women's Wages Slope")
    abline(a = -0.360, b = .185, col = "blue")
    abline(a = 0.077, b = 0.009, col = "red")
    legend("bottomright", c("Female", "Education"),
             col = c("blue", "red"), fill= c("blue", "red"), title="Legend", cex=.75)
```

[image: The PLot Output]
Where a(constant) is the intercept and b(standard error) is the slope (these values are taken from the stargazer table).

My main problem is I don't know how to run the model where I can evaluate female and male wage growth independently, that is where female = 1 or female = 0. I tried using `predict()` but the result it returns does not come in a format where I am able to get the coefficients in I need to plot into plot()

The results of this exercise should look something like this:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please make sure to note where your data comes from (in this case the `np` package).

Your intuition of using the `predict` function was one way of doing it but I would recommend using the `ggplot2` package to plot your regression results.

The easiest implementation of this is using the `geom_smooth` argument, which does the modelling automatically for you and because we specify a `color` argument, your interaction is taken into account:

```
library(np)
data(wage1)

ggplot(wage1, aes(x=educ, y=lwage, color=female))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

You could also use the `predict` function, as mentioned, but you have to run the model manually before (and adding the confidence intervals is a bit of a pain):

```
reg_wage1 <- lm(lwage ~ female + educ + (female * educ), data = wage1)
wage1$pred <- predict(reg_wage1)

ggplot(wage1, aes(x=educ, y=lwage, color=female))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(x = educ, y = pred, color=female))
```

Both lines have different slopes as well, although they are really difficult to see with your model. To reassure you that this is not just an intercept correction but also shows you different slopes, consider another example where the interaction effects are much stronger:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs)
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=hp,y=mpg,color=vs)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain how you got male and female separate in your first graph?

Comment: Please disregard that last message I figured out the reason why. Thank you so much Mr. Schwarz I really needed this help and the way you showed me is leagues better than what my professor wanted.

Comment: Great, I'm glad! :) 
Just for reference, as you will have realised, the ```color=female``` argument in ```ggplot2``` is what incorporates this difference (both visually as a color and then as interaction term in the geom_smooth).

If this was the answer you were looking for, I'd appreciate it if you could upvote it and select it as "solved" by clicking on the arrow on the left next to the answer.

Comment: Thank you I will,you've also helped me alot with the problem that comes after this one thanks alot :D